# Railsで画像以外のファイル（wordやpdf）をアップロードしたい

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

現在PaperClipを使っています。
画像以外のファイル（wordやpdf）をアップロードしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

また、PaperClip以外に便利なgemがあれば教えてください。

Comment: アップロードをするためにあなたが書いたコード、もしくはそのときに発生したエラー内容が知りたいところです。どんな問題があったのか興味があります。

Comment: いえ、画像以外のファイルアップロードでpaperclip以外に便利なgemがあったら教えてほしいということです。

Comment: 下記のリンクで同じ質問がなされています。
PaperClipを使えば、画像以外も扱えるようです。

[Paperclip - how do you upload PDFs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076041/paperclip-how-do-you-upload-pdfs)

Comment: ありがとうございます！たすかります！

Comment: 自己解決でも、もし解決しましたら、解決に使用したコードを含めて回答として張り付けて、この質問が解決したことを訪問者に伝えてくださいませ。 @Shunya_Ueta さんか他の方が、コード付きで回答してもかまいません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PaperClipでも画像以外のファイルをアップロードできるようです。

こちらのページではCSVファイルのアップロード例が載っています。

http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20140716/1405443484

> 画像以外のファイルアップロードでpaperclip以外に便利なgemがあったら教えてほしい

僕はよくCarrierWaveを使っています。

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

ネットの情報は画像アップロードを前提にしたものが多いですが、PaperClipと同様、画像に限らずWordでもPDFでも何でもアップロード可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
これらのファイルもアップロード可能なようですね！　
助かりました。